# html table - collapse all but one column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a html table with several columns. In case the table does not fit in the page horizontally, I would like all but one column to collapse (instead of a horizontal scrollbar to appear on the page).

By collapse I mean: hiding the part of the content that does not not fit inside the cell.

How can I do that?

html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>this can collapse</td>
    <td>this can collapse</td>
    <td class="nocollapse">this should not collapse</td>
    <td>this can collapse</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
td.nocollapse {
  overflow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The button just shows the effect of a script that would collapse the columns. Use the code of the button's onclick function for if the screen width is too small.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      tr,  td {border:solid 1px black;padding:3px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapse">this can collapse</td>
        <td class="collapse">this can collapse</td>
        <td>this should not collapse</td>
        <td class="collapse">this can collapse</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="for (var el of document.querySelectorAll('td.collapse'))el.style.display='none';">Collapse</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you use jQuery, this becomes even easier with the button looking like: `<button onclick="$('td.collapse').hide();">Collapse</button>`